# How to write a method that can be shared by two non-inherited class

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, polymorphism

I am having 2 classes, both having a same method(name + type +behavior) and a same property (name + type)

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DisplayName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DisplayName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
    }
}
```

-- `Person` and `Country` classes are not allowed to inherit

In the above code you can see `Person` class has similar method(`DisplayName`) like `Country` class. I am looking for a way so that both classes can share the same method codes, i want to do this because in my real codes-  Method which i want to share is very big and whenever i change code in one class i have to copy paste it in other class too. That i feel is not the correct way.

Please suggest how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Why are `Person` and `Country` not allowed to inherit? The simplest solution is to create a common base class and put the duplicate properties and methods in that.

Comment: How about extracting `Name` to an interface and making `DisplayName` an extension-method on the interface?

Comment: Can `Country` and `Person` derive from a common interface?

Comment: You should not over engineer on this. Find a functional/technical requirement/problemen you want to solve with inheritance/interfaces.

Comment: @chrisF: because they are already inheriting from some other class.

Comment: @RusiNova - you should make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You say they cannot inherit from a common base class, but you could add an interface, right?  I suggest giving them each a common **interface**.  Then define an **[extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)** for that interface.  The method will appear for each of them in VS.

(*Assumption*: this will work if the class members accessed by the extension methods are public or internal.)

```
interface IDisplayable
{
    string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Country : IDisplayable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IDisplayable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void DisplayName(this iDisplayable d)
{
    return doSomeDisplayLogic(d.Name);
}
```

. . . And in the same class as your extension method, define (not as an extension method) a function doSomeDisplayLogic to do your common logic.  (first-time gotcha:  make sure the extension method is in the same Namespace or the its namespace is also included in the calling code.)

I don't know if you're new to extension methods or not.  They are very powerful.  (And like many powerful features, they can be abused).  An [extension method on an interface](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/05/interface-extension-methods-mixin.html) seems crazy at first, until you get straight in your head how extension methods really work.  LINQ wouldn't work without this!

**Update**:  I see your comment above that the classes can't inherit from a common class, because they are already inheriting from a common class (which I assume can't be messed with too much).  I would like to point out an **Option 2**, based on this:  Creating a new class that Country/Person/etc. will inherit from, that itself inherits from the existing common parent class.  The existing base class would become a *grandparent* class, so to speak.  This would become more the route to go if *Country* and *Person* have other common characteristics *besides* this DisplayName method.  If DisplayName is all you're after, the Interface/Extension pattern might be better.

Comment: IDisplayable is not a good name for such abstraction with single Name property, name is not clearly defines it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to avoid Extension Methods in some cases, you can ran into a problem when you need slightly a different implementation for both classes and then you have to design a more generic solution, EM can cause the same issues like multiple inheritance does.

As more generic OOD solution I would suggest to extract this behaviour into a separate service class abstracted by an interface:

```
public interface IDisplayService()
{
    void Display();
}
```

Then implement it and **inject** into both classes via constructor.

Also, instead of introducing the interfaces and new classes you can inject `Action` or `Func<>` via constructor or even property and then call this method by invoking an injected in delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface

```
public interface INameable
{
    string Name {get;}
}
```

then add an extension

```
public static class INameableExt
{
    public static void DisplayName(this INameable n)
    {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The `public` modifier on the interface property is not legal. Should just be `string Name { get; }`. (Interface members are implicitly public.)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- Make both classes implement an interface for the common members (`Name`) and add an extension method for the behaviour (or just a normal static method)
- Create methods which take an instance and a lambda exppession to access the comment members, e.g.

  ```
  public static void Display<T>(T item, Func<T, string> nameGetter)
  ```

  You'd then call it with (say)

  ```
  DisplayHelper.Display(person, p => p.Name);
  ```

The interface solution is the cleaner one, but using a delegate is more flexible - you don't need to be able to change the classes involved, and you can cope with small variations (e.g. `PersonName` vs `FooName` vs `Name`)

Comment: could you explain second methods a bit more!! thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You could create either a static utility method `DisplayName()` that you pass the data needed for display, or use composition and move all properties and corresponding methods such as `DisplayName()` in a separate class - then use an instance of this class from both `Country` and `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define that big method in a separate class and then call the method in both the above classes. For a static method, you can call the method using `classname.methodname()` syntax.

For a non static method, you will have to do this:

```
classname obj=new classname();
obj.methodname();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a strategy pattern:

```
class DisplayNameStrategy<T> {
    private readonly Func<T, string> nameSelector;
    public void DisplayNameStrategy(Func<T, string> nameSelector) {
        this.nameSelector = nameSelector;
    }

    public void abstract DisplayName(T t);
}

class WriteToConsoleDisplayNameStrategy<T> : DisplayNameStrategy<T> {
    public void WriteToConsoleDisplayNameStrategy(Func<T, string> nameSelector)
        : base(nameSelector) { }
    public override void DisplayName(T t) {
        Console.WriteLine(this.nameSelector(t));
}

public class Person {
    private readonly DisplayNameStrategy<Person> displayNameStrategy =
        new WriteToConsoleDisplayNameStrategy<Person>(x => x.Name);

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DisplayName() {
        this.displayNameStrategy(this);
    }
}
```

Note: it's probably better to inject the concrete strategy.

Answer (score 0):

What I THINK you are asking for is multiple class inheritance which is not allowed in C#. (but can be with C++ which you are NOT doing).

All the others have identified doing an INTERFACE solution, and probably the best way to go.  However, from your description, you have a SINGLE BLOCK of code that is identical regardless of the type of object being a person or a business.  And your reference to a huge block of code, you don't want to copy/paste that same exact code among all the other classes that may be intended to use similar common "thing" to be done.

For simple example, you have a functionality that builds out a person's name and address (or business name and address).  You have code that is expecting a name and up to 3 address lines, plus a city, state, zip code (or whatever else).  So, the formatting of such name/address information is the same for a person vs a business.  You don't want to copy this exact method over and over between the two.  However, each individual class still has its own things that it is responsible for.

I know its a simple example for context, but I think gets the point across.

The problem with just defining an Interface is that it won't allow you to actually implement the CODE you are referring to.

From your sample, I would consider doing a combination of things.. Create a static class with methods on it that you might want as "globally" available.  Allow a parameter to be passed into it of an instance of a class that has a type of interface all the others have expressed that will guarantee the incoming object has all the "pieces" of properties / methods you are expecting, and have IT operate on it as needed.   Something like

```
public interface ITheyHaveInCommon
{
   string Name;
   string GetOtherValue();
   int SomethingElse;
}

public class Person : ITheyHaveInCommon
{
  // rest of your delcarations for the required contract elements
  // of the ITheyHaveInCommon interface...
}

public class Country : ITheyHaveInCommon
{
  // rest of your delcarations for the required contract elements
  // of the ITheyHaveInCommon interface...
}


public static class MyGlobalFunctions
{
   public static string CommonFunction1( ITheyHaveInCommon incomingParm )
   {
      // now, you can act on ANY type of control that uses the 
      // ITheyHaveInCommon interface...
      string Test = incomingParm.Name
                  + incomingParm.GetOtherValue()
                  + incomingParm.SomethingElse.ToString();

      // blah blah with whatever else is in your "huge" function

      return Test;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use composition: define an interface, a class that implements it, and then have `Person` and `Country` implement the interface by calling methods on the implementation class:

```
// the interface
public interface IName {
    string Name { get; set; }
    void DisplayName();
}

// a class that implements the interface with actual code
public class NameImpl : IName {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DisplayName() {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
    }
}

public class Country : IName {

    // instance of the class that actually implements the interface
    IName iname = new NameImpl();

    // forward calls to implementation
    public string Name {
        get { return iname.Name; }
        set { iname.Name = value; }
    }

    public void DisplayName() {
        // forward calls to implementation
        iname.DisplayName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

warning: lots of untested code here, wild guessing mostly since i disagree with the base assumption "no inheritance".

something like this should help you. create a new static class and paste your code in here.

```
public static class Display
{
    public static void DisplayName<T>(T obj)
    {
        if ((T is Person) || (T is Country) || (T is whateveryouwant))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

in your classes, refactor ShowDisplayName() to call that with "this" as parameter.

...
    public void  DisplayName()
    {
         DisplayName(this);
    }
...

I wonder why your classes are not allowed to inherit it from a base class, since that's imho the right-est way to solve this.